# Coding for auto click on ads in android studio

Tags: android-studio, automation, ads, admob

I want to coding for auto click on ads for the android studio, I mean when interstitial ad show then auto click on it.I know this is against the AdMob but I want to try this only for study purpose.Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, even if you do this you'll receive nothing as you're account will get **banned** as you're using a bot to automatically and **illegally** clicking on ads to receive reward.

About **Rewards**, you will receive nothing there too, because those clicks will be counted as **Accidental Clicks**.

So better to create a good app with good UI and publish with ads and earn rewards.

Have A Nice Day !

Answer (score 0):

Its absolutely against admob policy. You account might be suspended if detected. Yes you can create a bot that can click on the ad links but you wont get any revenue. Because admob can detect whether its a human click or bot click. From single device you wont get revenue.

Easy secret behind high revenue from admob is high active install and high usage of the app.